# How to have back the command prompt after calling an application

Tags: command-line

In terminal I just type `firefox` and then Firefox starts, but I can not return to
 *command mode* anymore.

How can I come back to *command mode*?
I have already tried `:q` or `exit`, but neither work.

Comment: If, by `command mode`, you mean the interactive shell, then no. You have run `firefox` in such a way so that the terminal will show its output. You can press `^C` to send `SIGINT` to `firefox`. Doing so will get you back to the interactive shell, but it will kill `firefox`. Instead, you can run `firefox` in the background (à la `firefox &`), and you should already be back to the interactive shell once the process has forked off.

Comment: ...`firefox &` is the right way. If you forget it you can do CRTL-Z to suspend it and after `%1 &` to execute it in  background.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run a program from a shell (e.g. `firefox`) it will be executed *"in foreground"*. When the program will finish you will have back the possibility to execute another command.

Another way to execute a command is **"in background"**. If you put this symbol **`&`** after the command it will be executed asynchronously (in background) and you will have the possibility to execute other commands from the same shell/terminal. Excerpt from `man bash`:

```
When bash starts a job asynchronously  (in the background), it prints a line
that looks like:  

          [1] 25647

indicating  that this job is job number 1 and that the process ID of the 
last process in the pipeline associated with this job is 25647.
```

When you start the second jobs it will answer with `[2] NewPid`  and so on. With the built-in command `jobs` you will have all the list.

When you run a command *"in foreground"* and you want **to suspend it** (not to stop definitively) you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. The shell will answer you in a similar way (e.g.)

```
 [1]+  Stopped                 firefox
```

**To continue the precedent job** you can write **`%1 &`** (the same number you read from the terminal). You can also do it with **`bg %1`**. It will execute the *job 1* in background and give you the prompt back, ready to accept new commands.

You may find interesting the article [Linux: Start Command In Background](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-line-run-in-background/)

Comment: This answer would be even better if it stated how to push commands onto the process [1]. E.g. I tell my package manager `cabal` to first `update` then after it finishes I want it to install package `x`.

Comment: @Owen,  On this site usually One question one answer... _but not one answer to rule them all_ (imagine this phrase said with the voice from the Lord of The Rings when they speak about "The" ring). Assuming a syntax similar to `apt`, you can always do something like `apt update && apt install PackageX` where you execute the 1st command (here not in background) and then the second command (apt install PackageX) only if the 1st one exits without errors (`&&`). To be honest for your example it should be enough `;`, but it is better to install only if the update went ok (then `&&`).